# JWE in Salesforce apex

Tags: jwt, salesforce

I'd like to send a callout with a JWE as the request body.

Header:

```
{
    "alg": "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "enc": "A128CBC-HS256",
    "cty": "JWT",
    "kid": "XXX"
}
```

I have an apex class to encrypt in RSA (with OAEP) that seems to be working. It can decrypt what it encrypted. It's based on https://gist.github.com/nikitakarpenkov/7a39c5cd6170dbcac74cf797d03e60f7

I used the standard crypto class to generate the CEK (and used the second half for the payload encryption, the first to generate a MAC), encrypt the payload (encryptWithManagedIV with algo AES128) and generate the authentication tag (generateMAC with algo hmacSHA256). But https://dinochiesa.github.io/jwt/ doesn't recognize what I did as a proper JWE (it says it can't decrypt the payload). So I suspect the problem is in the second section of the JWE, the encrypted CEK. It's also possible I didn't use the right input to generate the MAC I used as the authentication tag, but I assume I would have had another error message?

Is there any way I could check where I went wrong?